# mainCRTStartup without Visual Studio installed

Tags: c, winapi, lld

Is there a way to link in mainCRTStartup without having Visual Studio installed?  I have libcmt.lib in my Visual Studio installation, and that works fine for linking against on my computer.  However, I would like to be able to build and link without having to have Visual Studio installed.

I am using Clang and LLD 9.0.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: vs is only integrated shell, convenient to use. it not need for compile/build/run any pe.

Comment: That was my thought.  However, I can't think of how to get away from having it installed other than rewriting mainCRTStartup (which I don't want to do).

Comment: for what you need Visual Studio installed ? only for get crt includes/src ?

Comment: For a definition of mainCRTStartup.

Comment: how is VS related to definition ?

Comment: @rbm: The runtime libraries are part of the language implementation. The language implementation is part of Visual Studio.

Comment: If you need the Visual C++ libraries, but do not want to install the full Visual Studio suite, you can download the [Build Tools for Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019) separately.

Comment: Why do you need to link in `mainCRTStartup`? What kind of C program is this?

Comment: mainCRTStartup is the function called by Windows that eventually calls main.

Comment: That's incorrect. Windows calls whatever you specify as the `/ENTRYPOINT`. Microsoft's tooling uses one of the `*CRTStartup` functions, that set up the runtime environment before calling into the user-provided entry point. The raw entry point is an implementation detail of the language implementation. Clang may or may not use Microsoft's defaults on Windows. You'll have to investigate that.

Comment: I don't believe that clang provides an entry point implementation.  It does compile and link to needing mainCRTStartup, which is the reason for the question.

Comment: Clang is a language implementation. The language runtime is part of the language implementation. Clang ships its own language runtime, but attempts to be [ABI compatible with MSVC](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MSVCCompatibility.html), so you *can* link with MSVC's C and C++ runtimes.